# Keyboard passthrough - random key inputs while gaming

Tags: arch-linux, windows, kvm, qemu, manjaro

I have a Windows 10 VM setup with KVM (qemu). I am passing through my mouse and keyboard input.
I looked up the device under `/dev/input/by-id/` and added them to the XML:

```xml
<input type="mouse" bus="virtio">
  <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x0b" slot="0x00" function="0x0"/>
</input>
<input type="keyboard" bus="virtio">
  <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x0c" slot="0x00" function="0x0"/>
</input>
<input type="mouse" bus="ps2"/>
<input type="keyboard" bus="ps2"/>
```

```xml
<qemu:commandline>
  <qemu:arg value="-object"/>
  <qemu:arg value="input-linux,id=mouse1,evdev=/dev/input/by-id/usb-Razer_Razer_DeathAdder_Elite-event-mouse"/>
  <qemu:arg value="-object"/>
  <qemu:arg value="input-linux,id=kbd1,evdev=/dev/input/by-id/usb-Gaming_KB_Gaming_KB-event-kbd,grab_all=on,repeat=on"/>
</qemu:commandline>
```

My mouse is working fine, but my keyboard is not. When doing productive work I haven't yet noticed any inconveniences, but when gaming... constantly getting unwanted input:

- Continuously walking in one direction
- Random weapon switches (seems like repeating key inputs, because it's only switching between the same weapon I used before)
- Random key inputs (opens esc menu)

I tried different things to improve it:

- editing Windows key repetition thing, that it activates as late as possible and as slow as possible
- adding the xml part with `bus="virtio"`
- and some smaller things too, but can't remember them all

Did someone else have the same problem and solved it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case everything was set up correctly, but I forgot installing the virtio drivers on windows.

I had to download the virtio-win iso, load it as a cd-rom and then update the drivers of devices, which haven't had a driver yet, by selecting the root dir of the iso (not a specific directory).